# How can I debug Droidwall blocking every app?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, firewall, iptables

Starting some time ago, I have noticed that when Droidwall (1.5.7) is enabled, no apps can access wifi.

Although the app is checked, it doesn't work, until I turn the firewall completely off. This has happened for some time, is this a known bug with Droidwall or Android 2.2?

Running `iptables -L` shows this, among others:

```
Chain droidwall-wifi (4 references)
target   prot opt source              destination
droidwall-reject 0  --  anywhere             anywhere
droidwall-reject 0  --  anywhere             anywhere
droidwall-reject 0  --  anywhere             anywhere
droidwall-reject 0  --  anywhere             anywhere
droidwall-reject 0  --  anywhere             anywhere
droidwall-reject 0  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have it set in whitelist mode or blacklist mode? And have you clicked "apply rules"?

Comment: Yes I applied rules multiple times, I finally saw that the top "mode" was blacklist, tapping the title and selecting "whitelist (allow selected)" fixes it! Please post this as the answer, this is easy to miss as it doesn't look like a button/setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the behavior if you have blacklist mode enabled. Double check the (subtle) whitelist/blacklist default button (the text above the apps listing).